# Transform dataframe rows with lists of items into rows with pairs of items

Tags: python, pandas

df1 looks something like:

```
dateA; item1; item2; item3; item4; itemN...
dateB; item5; item2; item3; item6; itemN...
```

df2 should look like:

```
dateA; item1; item2
dateA; item1; item3
dateA; item1; item4
dateA; item2; item3
etc.
```

Every row in df2 should have three columns,
and df2 as a whole should contain dated *pairs* that
occur together on the same row in df1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
import io
data = """dateA; item1; item2; item3; item4; itemN
dateB; item5; item2; item3; item6; itemN
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(data), sep=";", header=None, skipinitialspace=True, index_col=0)

from itertools import combinations, chain
df2 = df[list(chain.from_iterable(combinations(df.columns, 2)))]

df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(df2.shape[1]//2), ["A", "B"]])

print df2.stack(level=0)
```

output:

```
             A      B
0                    
dateA 0  item1  item2
      1  item1  item3
      2  item1  item4
      3  item1  itemN
      4  item2  item3
      5  item2  item4
      6  item2  itemN
      7  item3  item4
      8  item3  itemN
      9  item4  itemN
dateB 0  item5  item2
      1  item5  item3
      2  item5  item6
      3  item5  itemN
      4  item2  item3
      5  item2  item6
      6  item2  itemN
      7  item3  item6
      8  item3  itemN
      9  item6  itemN
```

**EDIT**

since not every row has the same count of items, you need following code:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import io
txt = """1975;a;b
1976;b;c;d;e;f
1977;b;a
1977;a;b;g
1978;c;d
1979;e;f;b;k
1980;a;f"""

f = io.BytesIO(txt) # change this line to f = open("yourfile.csv")
result = []
for line in f:
    data = line.strip().split(";")
    year = data[0]
    for row in itertools.combinations(data[1:], 2):
        result.append((year,) + row)
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
print df
```

Comment: Yes @HYRY, but also with 'dateA' and 'dateB' filling down throughout the column.

Comment: Also, after importing my data from csv, then moving on in the suggested way, I get: `TypeError: 'DataFrame' does not have the buffer interface`

Answer (score 0):

```
from pandas import read_csv
import io
data = read_csv('/Users/Simon/Dropbox/Work/Datasets/lagtest.csv')
df = read_csv(io.BytesIO(data), sep=";", header=None, skipinitialspace=True, index_col=0)
```

The above code halts with the error:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' does not have the buffer interface
```

A print of 'data' looks like this:

```
         1975;a;b
0  1976;b;c;d;e;f
1        1977;b;a
2      1977;a;b;g
3        1978;c;d
4    1979;e;f;b;k
5        1980;a;f

[6 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: So, the count of items in every rows are different. You can't use the method I posted. I will modify the code. And since you already read the csv file into a DataFrame, the second `read_csv()` is unnecessary